# Amazon Echo DIY with Matrix Creator

Tags: matrix-creator

I would like to create an Amazon Echo using the Matrix Creator connected with to a Raspberry Pi.

My actual idea is use a beamforming algorithm to define the direction of the sound and turn on an LED according to the direction detected. Do you think it's possible with Matrix Creator? How can I get the stream from the microphones? Is there any ready software?

Comment: Welcome to the RPi StackExchange. If you haven't already, please read the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour). As it is currently written, your question is more of a discussion, which makes it off topic. If you have specific questions about various parts of the project, we can help, but as is, it's too broad for this format.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the question! You can see an example on how to get a stream in the following example:
https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-hal/blob/master/demos/mic_demo.cpp

```cpp
/*
 * Copyright 2016 <Admobilize>
 * All rights reserved.
 */

#include <wiringPi.h>

#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

#include "../cpp/driver/microphone_array.h"
#include "../cpp/driver/everloop_image.h"
#include "../cpp/driver/everloop.h"
#include "../cpp/driver/wishbone_bus.h"

namespace hal = matrix_hal;

int main() {
  hal::WishboneBus* bus = new hal::WishboneBus();
  bus->SpiInit();

  hal::Everloop everloop;
  everloop.Setup(bus);

  hal::MicrophoneArray mics;
  mics.Setup(bus);

  hal::EverloopImage image1d;

  std::valarray<int> lookup = {23, 27, 32, 1, 6, 10, 14, 19};

  std::valarray<float> magnitude(hal::kChannels);

  while (true) {
    mics.Read();
    magnitude = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int s = 0; s < mics.NumberOfSamples(); s++) {
      for (unsigned int c = 0; c < hal::kChannels; c++) {
        magnitude[c] += mics.At(s, c) * mics.At(s, c);
      }
    }

    for (auto& m : magnitude) {
      m = std::sqrt(1.0 / (float)mics.NumberOfSamples() * m);
    }

    for (unsigned int c = 0; c < hal::kChannels; c++) {
      image1d.leds[lookup[c]].red = magnitude[c] / 255;
      std::cout << image1d.leds[lookup[c]].red << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    everloop.Write(&image1d);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

We'll be updating the examples next week as well so keep checking out the wiki:
https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-quickstart/wiki

Comment: While your answer may provide the help needed, it doesn't do much to explain how. Additionally, you haven't explicitly disclosed if you're affiliated with this product, which makes it iffy for the spam rules.

Comment: I think it would be better to keep the more pertinent parts of the code here and explain them. As you've linked to it, the code can be downloaded by the user on github, so copying the entire thing without additional information doesn't seem particularly helpful.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for your help. This is the code to get the streaming from the matrix to the pi. Right? Do you something to implement the beamfoarming?

Answer (score 2):

We (MATRIX Creator development team) have  posted another *bare metal* example about reading a raw audio stream from the FPGA:

https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-hal/blob/master/demos/micarray_recorder.cpp

We still working in the beamforming algorithms, we will release the code soon.

Answer (score 1):

We have published the first recipe to make a Amazon Echo DIY device using a Raspberry Pi + MATRIX Creator.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-a-DIY-Amazons-Alexa-With-a-Raspberry-Pi-and-/